# Intellij idea cannot resolve jdk 9

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9

I am trying to set JDK 9 as project sdk but it cannot resolve java main classes. When I set JDK 8 as project sdk, it works without any problem.

Do I need to do something extra to set JDK 9?

[image]

Here is libraries;

[image]

Intellij Version: 2016.2

JDK Version: jdk-9.0.4 (Windows 64 Bit)

Comment: 2016.2 is too old for JDK 9. Use 2017.3.

Comment: [*IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 brings support for Java 9’s new modularity*](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/support-for-java-9-modules-in-intellij-idea-2017-1/)